# postgres creates table having trouble

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists `blue_async_cmd`
         (
             `id`              int(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
             `task_id`              varchar(64)  NOT NULL,
             `type`            tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
             `cmd`    varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
             `createTime`   datetime DEFAULT NULL,
             PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
             KEY `blue_async_cmd_index_taskId` (`task_id`)
             ) ENGINE = InnoDB
             DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
```

[2022-08-29 12:47:50] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"
[2022-08-29 12:47:50] 位置：28

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)  those dreaded backticks are invalid in SQL. There is also no `auto_increment` in Postgres. [As also documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html) there is no data type `tinyint` or `datetime` in Postgres. [As further documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)  there is no `key` , `engine` option or `default charset` option for the `create table statement.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run a MySQL statement on a PostgreSQL database

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a valid postgres SQL statement. Maybe that helps to update yours.

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR ( 255 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    last_login TIMESTAMP 
);
```

Comment: The standard compliant `identity` columns are [recommended](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) over the proprietary `serial` pseudo-type